# expo push:android:upload is not supported in the local CLI, please use eas credentials instead

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo

I just started using expo and i use it in bare react native app. I'm trying to use expo-notification. I followed this guide to upload the server key to expo: https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/using-fcm/#uploading-server-credentials

But when i run this command

```
npx expo push:android:upload --api-key AAABCD:bbbbsdjwdhwdjhdjdjwejwekwe............
```

it's show an error:

```
expo push:android:upload is not supported in the local CLI, please use eas credentials instead
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Expo with EAS, you should do this using the following command:

```
eas credentials -p android
```

Just found out the solution. Hope it's not too late.

Answer (score 0):

just paste

```
expo credentials:manager
```

this is working for me

Comment: Are you sure you had the same issue? That gives me the same error: `expo credentials:manager is not supported in the local CLI, please use eas credentials instead`. The best thing to do is migrate to eas-cli.